# Mysql PDO prepare statement issue with DATE data type

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have trouble with date data type.
I have a php mysql pdo statement:

```
$mystmt = $mydb->prepare("
    SELECT  `ad_id` 
        FROM `tbl_actions`
        WHERE 
            (`actiondate` > :nowcookietime  )
");
$mystmt->execute(array(
            ':nowcookietime'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-$cookiedurationlock),
           )
);
$testnotinsql = $mystmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // EMPTY
```

The code run return empty. But if i get the sql below from general_log and run in sql tool (HeidiSQL), it will return record.
SQL from general_log:

```
SELECT  ad_id 
        FROM tbl_actions
        WHERE 
            (actiondate> '2012-08-24 17:53:21' )
```

My PHP timezone is UTC+7
Mysql is SYSTEM (which UTC)
As I understand it's not timezone problem if insert and query in php using same timezone.

I test the bind parameter with force string

```
':nowcookietime'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-$cookiedurationlock),
```

but it's same empty.

BUT: if use quote then it return rows

```
':nowcookietime'=>"'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-$cookiedurationlock)."'",
```

Can you clarify what wrong with this statement as I understand we dont need quote, mysql pdo quote for us.

**EDIT 1:**

I update the correct sql. With quote in sql is my mistake when take from test. The without quote around :nowcookietime stil empty.

**CLOSED**
See my answer below.

Comment: try this ':nowcookietime'=>"'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-$cookiedurationlock)."'"

Comment: Just remove the quotes around your `:nowcookietime` in the prepared statement. `(actiondate > :nowcookietime  )` is how it should be and run the code again.

Comment: is it the right datatype? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Comment: @N.B Sorry my mistake. The sql dont have quote in sql, it take from my test. Without quote in sql, it return empty. I updated my question.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about the general_log, checking this log helped identify my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out why.

1. Basicly there's script set the $cookiedurationlock too short, so most the time it empty.
2. When add quote, the comparation will be (`actiondate` > '\'2012-08-25 02:28:22\''  ), so it will return rows.
3. After the query, there is a insert new action row. So when i run trace sql from tools, data was change and it return the new one which added after this sql.

I think I have to organize my script to simpler ones.
Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As N.B. said in the comment use

```
(actiondate > :nowcookietime)
```

without the single-quotes around :nowcookietime in the sql statement.

Self-contained example:

```
<?php
$mydb = setup();
$cookiedurationlock = 40;
$mystmt = $mydb->prepare("
    SELECT  `ad_id` 
        FROM `tmp_tbl_actions`
        WHERE 
            (`actiondate` > :nowcookietime )
");
$mystmt->execute(array(
    ':nowcookietime'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()-$cookiedurationlock),
));
$testnotinsql = $mystmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($testnotinsql);


function setup() {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tbl_actions (
            ad_id int auto_increment,
            actiondate DATETIME,
            primary key(ad_id),
            key(actiondate)
        )
    ');

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tmp_tbl_actions (actiondate) VALUES(?)');
    $t = time();
    for($i=-80; $i<10; $i++) {
        $stmt->execute(array(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t+$i)));
    }
    return $pdo;
}
```

prints

```
array(1) {
  ["ad_id"]=>
  string(2) "42"
}
```

The colon in

```
':nowcookietime'=>date(...
```

is probably superfluous, but it's also used in Example #2 at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The sql dont have quote in sql, it take from my test. Without quote in sql, it also return empty. I updated my question. I will test your script with and without timezone set to see what happen. thanks

Comment: your code run correct, but my code still wrong. I will take out my code to separated script to test again.